# replicate lxd bridge in /etc/network/interfaces and dnsmasq

Tags: lxc, dnsmasq, containers, bridged-adapter

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 server and default LXD configuration.

Typically, when an image comes up, this happens:

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ae:ed:ea:69:41  
          inet addr:192.168.0.3  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::baae:edff:feea:6941/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:116948 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:59726 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:161031770 (161.0 MB)  TX bytes:4656462 (4.6 MB)
          Interrupt:16 Memory:df100000-df120000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:177 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:177 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:13388 (13.3 KB)  TX bytes:13388 (13.3 KB)

lxdbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:5c:57:cd:bd:72  
          inet addr:10.41.63.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fd6d:c772:b128:ebfd::1/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::d08c:f9ff:fed9:5cd1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:39 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:78 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5064 (5.0 KB)  TX bytes:11128 (11.1 KB)

vethD7L5U9 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:5c:57:cd:bd:72  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc5c:57ff:fecd:bd72/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:39 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:75 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5610 (5.6 KB)  TX bytes:10322 (10.3 KB)
```

And the image looks like this:

```
+-------+---------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
| NAME  |  STATE  |        IPV4         |                     IPV6                      |    TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |
+-------+---------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
| first | RUNNING | 10.41.63.206 (eth0) | fd6d:c772:b128:ebfd:216:3eff:fe9d:ef41 (eth0) | PERSISTENT | 0         |
+-------+---------+---------------------+-----------------------------------------------+------------+-----------+
```

I would like to take the option of using my own bridge as this is an option in reconfiguration. It seems it's not as simple as I thought.

I create a simple bridge.

```
iface vbr0 inet static
        address 10.10.10.1
        broadcast 255.255.255.0
        pre-up          brctl addbr vbr0
        post-down       brctl delbr vbr0
```

I restart my container and don't get an IP.

```
+-------+---------+------+------+------------+-----------+
| NAME  |  STATE  | IPV4 | IPV6 |    TYPE    | SNAPSHOTS |
+-------+---------+------+------+------------+-----------+
| first | RUNNING |      |      | PERSISTENT | 0         |
+-------+---------+------+------+------------+-----------+
```

But do get veth come up.

```
vbr0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:da:17:ca:ab:e0  
          inet addr:10.10.10.1  Bcast:255.255.255.0  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::e83b:1aff:fe18:4652/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:36 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7632 (7.6 KB)  TX bytes:908 (908.0 B)

vethWLPBCC Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:da:17:ca:ab:e0  
          inet6 addr: fe80::fcda:17ff:feca:abe0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:19 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4410 (4.4 KB)  TX bytes:948 (948.0 B)
```

The is no dnsmasq running (which one would expect) so I'm not sure where that comes into play. If I run it by hand, my containers get IP addresses (after restart).

Can someone give pointers as how to replicate the lxdbr0 bridge and consequential dnsmasq instantiation?

Answer (score 0):

## Bridge + dnsmasq guest networking

Looks like you're missing two steps that LXC / LXD normally handles for you. With LXC, this is handled by the `lxc-net` service.

Fundamentally, what happens is this:

1. The bridge is created
2. A `dnsmasq` instance is started, listening on the bridge interface
3. `iptables` rules are added to provide NAT, DHCP, and basic ICMP traffic.

You can see this exact behavior if you look at the source for the `lxc-net` init scripts. (and probably the `lxd` equivalent)

## Deploying it

You could either:

1. Copy and modify the lxc-net script from lxc / your distribution (look in `/etc/init/lxc-net` or by going here: [lxc-net (official master)](https://github.com/lxc/lxc/blob/master/config/init/common/lxc-net.in).

   - Place it in your init scripts (`/etc/init/`) and name it something unique. You can then start / stop it as if it was it's own service.
2. Write your own script, based off of the existing ones.

You'll want to add this script in place of your `pre-up` / `post-down` commands. Be sure it's marked as executable.